# Toggle two views with same constraints, one is wrong aligned

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints

I'm trying to toggle between 2 tableviews based on a segment control. To do this, I've tested 2 implementations:

Option A: Have 2 container views stacked in a storyboard (same constraints), then toggle the container views based on the segment control.

Option B: Have 1 container view setup, add and remove the views programmatically.

The problem with both implementations is that the first view to display is always aligned correctly (no matter if its view A or view B), the second one is wrong aligned! rrrr

Why is the second view to display wrong aligned!?!?

Here is the code for example A:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewOne: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewTwo: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentContrl: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showView(0)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func showView(index:Int){

    switch index
    {
        case 0:
            viewOne.hidden = false
            viewTwo.hidden = true
            break;

        case 1:
            viewOne.hidden = true
            viewTwo.hidden = false
            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
}

@IBAction func onSegmentChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("onSegmentChanged \( segmentContrl.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    showView(segmentContrl.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```

Storyboard, the container views are stacked:
[image: storyboard]
The container views constraints, both have the same!
[image: constraints]

Comment: Can we see some code ? Also note that removing a view from its superview also remove the contraints which a not readied when you add the view in its original superview. If you want to keep constraints, you should use the `hidden` property.

Comment: Added code example for Option A. Please note that if I only use one container view to display either view A or B without any toggle logic, both container views work correctly. Odd! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by removing "Adjust scroll view insets" in all 3 view controllers shown above.

Then I repositioned the container views to top and bottom align then to the layout guides.

WORKS! :P